# pyspark to read data from sql server

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I'm trying to read data from sql server using pyspark. Below mentioned code works fine when executed using following command (where i'm passing sqljdbc driver path) but it fails when i try to run it using PyCharm IDE(on windows).

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path C:\drivers\sqljdbc_6.0.8112.100_enu\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar ReadSQLServerData.py
```

How to include or set the driver path while running same code through PyCharm IDE?

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ReadSQLServerData")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
query = "(SELECT top 10 * from users) as users"
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver:1433;database=user_management;user=pyspark;password=pyspark", dbtable=query).load()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Mine/OneDrive/Python/PySpark01/ReadSQLServerData.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver:1433;database=user_management;user=pyspark;password=pyspark", dbtable=query).load()
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 155, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if  you figured this out but figured I could help others.

You have to set the driver-class-path and you can pass it in as a config option like below

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/Users/Desktop/drivers/sqljdbc42.jar") \
.getOrCreate()
```